# How to load static data/ table?

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I have a static table around 100 000 records. How should I use realm so that it can save my time? As I know I can put my static table (in case of sqlite) directly in assets and can access it's data.

Is there any way to put static data (rows), so that I can save my time to manually enter the data?

I already used realm's

```
realm.createAllFromJson("myfile")
```

But for this I have to put **myfile** in assets folder, and I guess it will need double the disk space.

Comment: A SQLite database cannot be used directly from `assets` either. It must be copied into the filesystem as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two restrictions why this is impossible now.

1. Any sqlite database is stored inside a particular path:
   '//data/data//databases/'
   To get access to any database you have to use a path
2. You can only get data from assets (or raw) in order to copy to somewhere. This is not possible to manipulate with SQLite without namely 'file' data.

That's why you have to copy data from app resourses into filesystem. Imho, this is ugly but I had not found another solution.
Android default API (Realm uses it) use only the files stored in 'databases' folder.